# How to retrieve internal information/variables from ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I've made a histogram of 10000 random points using the following code:

```
require(ggplot2)
data = data.frame(x = rnorm(10000))
ggplot(data, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image: histogram]

Now I want to draw a vertical line indicating the position of the 5000th point. That is, count from the leftmost bin all the way till you reach 5000. Add a vertical line at that position.

To do this I need the information from geom_histogram(), telling me how many points are in each bin, and then I can use this information to calculate the position of the 5000th point.

Is there a way to do this?

---

**Update:**

To illustrate, here is an example. Let's say there are 4999 points smaller than 0.1 and 5000 points larger than 0.1, therefore 0.1 is the 5000th point. Suppose it happens to be in the bin [0, 0.5]. There are 3 points in the bin, with values 0.1, 0.2, 0.3. I don't want the vertical line to appear at position x=0.1, but x=(0.5-0)*(1/3) = 0.167.

Comment: Maybe something in `ggplot_build(p)` can help (where p is your plot)

Comment: Exchange `data$x[5000]` by `sort(data$x)[5000]` in @BondedDust`s example and you got the position. Info from `geom_histogram`, which you get by `ggplot_build(p)`, could be useful for e.g. marking begins of bins or whole bins like `dat <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]; p + geom_rect(data = dat[cumsum(dat$count) >= 5000, ][1, ], aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), fill = "red")` (where `p` contains the ggplot object).

Answer (score 0):

The comments may be relevant since it is not needed to know anything about the bins to determine where the 5000th value is:

```
require(ggplot2); set.seed(42)  # to make reproducible
data = data.frame(x = rnorm(10000))
ggplot(data, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram()+
       geom_vline(aes(xintercept=data$x[5000]) )
```

[image]

(I did search for a duplicate first.)

Comment: Clearly the number of points at the left of your line is not equal to the number of points at the right of your line. Maybe I'm not describing it clearly enough. I'm looking for the 5000th point counting from the leftmost bin.

Comment: Maybe `xintercept=quantile(data$x, probs=0.5)`?

Comment: There is no ordering of the points in the bins. If you wanted the `median` or line between the two center bins or perhaps the mid-point of the "middle bin", then you should have asked for it.